# 2 DKIM on same domain

Tags: dkim, domainkeys

We are using an external service for our newsletter, which has required the followin DKIM setup in our domain **gipote.dk**:

```
_domainkey.gipote.dk.   43200   IN  TXT "o=~"
default._domainkey.gipote.dk. 43200 IN  TXT "k=rsa\; p=MIGf...ibnrkoqQIDAQAB"
```

(I truncated the public key for purpose of readability...)

However we are also sending out e-mail from our own server, which I would also like to sign.

Is it possible to have more than one public-key TXT record in our domain gipote.dk? If so, how should it be set up?

**EDIT:** I do not have access to the private key, that is used by the newsletter service. So I will not be able to just install that on my own server.

/ Carsten

Comment: i have the same public key btw. how can that be possible ?!? is it because we used -t while generating keys?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found out, that the answer is YES :-)

"default" can easily be replaced with another selector name.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can change the default to another selector.
BUT if you do the domain it is on will no longer verify the domain.

You need to Add a second key NOT CHANGE whats existing 
using Google mail you end up with

default._domainkey "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIIBIj....."
google._domainkey  "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIGfMA......"